# I want to catch this moment and work on it even if it happens again in the future (CA)

Tags: pine-script

```
em20 = ta.ema(close, 20)
em50 = ta.ema(close, 50)

Signal = ta.crossover(em20, em50)

CA = ta.valuewhen(Signal, close, 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `var` keyword lets you save a value while not reseting it over and over.

Fron the [documentation](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Variable_declarations.html):

> When the var keyword is used, the variable is only initilized once, on
> the first bar if the declaration is in the global scope, or the first
> time the local block is executed if the declaration is inside a local
> block. After that, it will preserve its last value on successive bars,
> until we reassign a new value to it. This behavior is very useful in
> many cases where a variable’s value must persist through the
> iterations of a script across successive bars.

You can use the functionality in order to preserve the value of `close` only on first `ta.crossover()` if you'll save the number of crosses and then save the value. Here is an example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

em20 = ta.ema(close, 20) 
em50 = ta.ema(close, 50)

var numberOfTimesCrossed = 0

Signal = ta.crossover(em20, em50)

if Signal
    numberOfTimesCrossed += 1

var CA = float(na)

if numberOfTimesCrossed == 1
    CA := ta.valuewhen(Signal, close, 0)

plot(nz(CA))
```